# How to remove duplicates and display only unique values in ViewSettingsItem?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am getting duplicate values in JSON array from backend and I want to remove the duplicate values and display only unique values in SAPUI5 ViewSettingsItem.

Please help me in this.

```
{
"d": {
    "results": [{       
        "Status": "Completed",
        "sId": "C1"
    }, 
    {       
        "Status": "Completed",
        "sId": "C1"
    },
    {       
        "Status": "Started",
        "sId": "S1"
    },
    {       
        "Status": "In Process",
        "sId": "P1"
    },{     
        "Status": "Completed",
        "sId": "C1"
    }]
}
```

}

XML view:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <ViewSettingsDialog >
        <filterItems>
            <ViewSettingsFilterItem>
                <items>
                    <ViewSettingsItem text="{Status}" key="{sId}"/>
                </items> 
            </ViewSettingsFilterItem>
        </filterItems>
    </ViewSettingsDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: How you consider them unique ? just by SID or both SID and status ?

Comment: I consider them unique using "sId" .

Comment: Can`t you config the Sid as a primary key on your odata Backend? That way the duplicates won`t even make it to the client side.

Comment: @GeraldoMegale you can return multiple entities with the same keys. The backend doesn't care.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and an `Object` to keep track of previously added `sId's`

```js
let obj = {"d": {"results": [{"Status": "Completed","sId": "C1"}, {"Status": "Completed","sId": "C1"},{"Status": "Started","sId": "S1"},{"Status": "In Process","sId": "P1"},{"Status": "Completed","sId": "C1"}]}}

let track = {}

let results = obj.d.results.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  if(!track[inp.sId]){
    op.push(inp)
    track[inp.sId] = inp
  }
  return op
},[])

let op = {d:{results:results}}
console.log(op)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using javascript (no need to use ES6 specification) and jQuery.

```
  var obj = {"d": {"results": [{"Status": "Completed","sId": "C1"}, {"Status": "Completed","sId": "C1"},{"Status": "Started","sId": "S1"},{"Status": "In Process","sId": "P1"},{"Status": "Completed","sId": "C1"}]}}
    var uniqueNames = [];
/******************************************************************************/
    //check if el exist in array
    function inArray (array,el) {
      var find  = false;
      $.each(array,function(index,value) {
        if (el.sId === value.sId ) {
          find = true;
          return false
        }
      });
      return find;
    }
    /*************************************************************************/
   // remove duplicate object from the array
    $.each(obj.d.results,function(i, el) {
       if (this.inArray(uniqueNames,el) === false) {
         uniqueNames.push(el)
       }
    }.bind(this)),



    console.log(uniqueNames);
```

Here is a jsBin snippet : https://jsbin.com/vaxocor/edit?html,js,output

Comment: jQuery is obsolete in UI5.